# Show that if $a < b$ and $a \leq c$ then $b \leq c$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that if $a < b$ and $a \leq c$ then $b \leq c$.

I think it's false because when $a=c$ then $b>c$, which contradicts $b \leq c$. Yet, it's true according to the solution to a bigger problem I have. Either the solution is wrong or I'm wrong at something so basic.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the exact statement that was proposed in the solution?

Comment: I stripped the logic in the troublesome part of the solution as much as I could, but it should be correct. To mirror the solution more: $\forall a < b, a \leq c \implies b \leq c$. Does that change something?

Comment: In my opinion, it should be: If $a <b$ then have one of two statements is true: $c > a$ or $c<b$, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a false statement. Consider $a= 1$, $b = 3$, $c=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$1<3$ and $1\leq2$, but $3>2.$